# How to get two bars per value on the x-axis with ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, tidyverse

I'm trying to make a stacked bar plot with data that look something like this:

```
df <- tribble(
  ~Count, ~Date, ~Test_Type, ~Test_Target, ~Outcome,
  8, "Fall", "A", "H5", "Positive",
  7, "Fall", "A", "H5", "Negative",
  10, "Fall", "A", "H5", "Inconclusive",
  6, "Fall", "A", "H7", "Positive",
  11, "Fall", "A", "H7", "Negative",
  0, "Fall", "A", "H7", "Inconclusive",
  12, "Fall", "B", "H5", "Positive",
  6, "Fall", "B", "H5", "Negative",
  3, "Fall", "B", "H5", "Inconclusive",
  0, "Fall", "B", "H7", "Positive",
  7, "Fall", "B", "H7", "Negative",
  11, "Fall", "B", "H7", "Inconclusive",
  9, "Winter", "A", "H5", "Positive",
  5, "Winter", "A", "H5", "Negative",
  4, "Winter", "A", "H5", "Inconclusive",
  0, "Winter", "A", "H7", "Positive",
  13, "Winter", "A", "H7", "Negative",
  14, "Winter", "A", "H7", "Inconclusive",
  2, "Winter", "B", "H5", "Positive",
  1, "Winter", "B", "H5", "Negative",
  6, "Winter", "B", "H5", "Inconclusive",
  9, "Winter", "B", "H7", "Positive",
  17, "Winter", "B", "H7", "Negative",
  0, "Winter", "B", "H7", "Inconclusive",
)
```

I want `Date` on the x-axis, and `Count` on the y-axis, but I also want to separate by `Test_Type` *and* `Test_Target`, to get something that looks like this:
[image]

But the closest I can get is this, which combines the counts for/doesn't differentiate between `Test_Target`:

```
df %>% ggplot(aes(x = Date, fill = Outcome, y = Count)) +
  geom_col() +
  facet_grid(~factor(Test_Type, levels = c('A', 'B')))
```

[image]

Does anyone know how to separate by, or factor by, two columns in this way?

Any advice greatly appreciated!!

Comment: https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/position_dodge.html

Comment: Thanks! This doesn't quite get there, but I'll keep poking around!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ggplot2 offers a few ways to map data to horizontal position: facets, x axis, and dodging, through `position_dodge`. We could alternatively stack bars with `position_stack`, which is used implicitly with `geom_col` with multiple groups.

But there isn't a combined dodge+stack position calculation, so if we want a stacked column chart with three levels of division on the horizontal axis, one way is to figure out the vertical position manually and rely on `position_dodge()` for the horizontal positioning.

(added `geom_text` layer here to demonstrate that the bars are the right size.)

```
library(dplyr); library(ggplot2)
df %>%
  mutate(mid = cumsum(Count) - Count/2, .by = c(Date, Test_Target, Test_Type)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(Date, mid, height = Count, width = 0.8, fill = Outcome, group = Test_Target)) +
  geom_tile(position = position_dodge(width = 0.85)) +
  geom_text(aes(label = Count), position = position_dodge(width = 0.85)) +
  facet_wrap(~Test_Type)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks so much for this! Exactly what I was looking for, and not at all how I was trying to do it––perfect! Thanks!